# PersistentCookieJar to SharedPrefs from response with OKHTTP3

Tags: android, token, okhttp

I´ve got a trouble with the [PersistentCookieJar](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar). I want to implement a static HTTP-Client with [OKHTTP3](https://github.com/square/okhttp), whereby I can call my different methods from the activities and save the token from the response to SharedPrefs. When I do this following the docs on Github...

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
            new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

    public static OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build();
```

...I get an error 'Non-static field 'cookieJar' cannot be referenced from a static context'. Ok! Sure, so I've tried the different solutions, AndroidStudio gave me (like make the class non-static...) but nothing helps me to solve the problem. Another way to "solve" this (as Android Studio says) is to declare the `ClearableCookieJar`static, then I get trouble with getting the context... Can somebody help me solving this prob?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the fact that one is static and not the other. Therefore if you remove `static` from your `OkHttpClient` (like Android Studio suggested) it should work fine:

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
            new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build();
```

The issue now is why you want your `OkHttpClient` to be `static` in the first place. If you want to be able to access your client from more than one place in your application, why not initialize it in your `Application` class?

```
public class CustomApplication extends Application {

    private static OkHttpClient sOkHttpClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        initializeClient();
    }

    private void initializeClient() {
        ClearableCookieJar cookieJar = new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));

        sOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .cookieJar(cookieJar)
                .build();
    }

    public static OkHttpClient getClient() {
        return sOkHttpClient;
    }

}
```

Or if you want to get fancy, you can implement a dependency injection framework, like [`Dagger`](http://square.github.io/dagger/).

Comment: so if I do this (initialize it in the `Application` class), I get the same error 'non-static field 'mOkHttpClient' cannot be referenced from a static context' :/

Comment: @Andy I'm sorry, I forgot the `static` modifier on `mOkHttpClient`, that should fix it.